# Python: how to find correlation between two values and remove noise?

Tags: python, signal-processing, pearson-correlation

I have two curves `A` and `B` like that are highly correlated as shown in the figure below where `C` is the Pearson correlation between `A` and `B`.

The file containing the data can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dakxpehajzqirie/prova.csv?dl=0).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt

df = pd.read_csv('prova.csv')
A = df['A'].values
B = df['B'].values
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr 
C = pearsonr(A,B)[0]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(20, 5))
ax1 = ax[0]
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(A, 'g-')
ax2.plot(B, 'b-')
ax1.set_ylabel('A', color='g', fontsize=20);
ax2.set_ylabel('B', color='b', fontsize=20);


ax2 = ax[1]
txt = 'C = %.2f'%C
ax2.scatter(A, B, label=txt)
ax2.set_xlabel('A', color='g', fontsize=20);
ax2.set_ylabel('B', color='b', fontsize=20);
ax2.legend(fontsize = 16)
```

The values of the green curve should be `0` but the signal is affected by `B`. I would like to find the relation between `A` and `B` in order to be for `A` and `B` to cancel out, but I am unsure how to proceed.

[image: Data and correlation plot]

Comment: Can you provide a complete example, including some data?

Comment: I can share the data in a drive. Let me do that.

Comment: @N.Wouda did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, `A` and `B` predict each other quite well. We can exploit this to ensure we obtain a value at about `0` given values of `A` and `B`. My method of choice is the [`least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) fit.

We want to minimize `A - x * B - c` for some parameters `x` and `c`. This can be done using,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize as opt


df = pd.read_csv('prova.csv')

def fit(x):
    return df['A'] - x[0] * df['B'] - x[1]


result = opt.least_squares(fit, [0, 0])

fit(result.x).plot()
plt.show()
```

This results in,

[image: Result]

Which is many orders of magnitude closer to zero.

Comment: great! Do you have other references to suggest?